# How can I change the natural tab order of only part of an html document?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in the middle of my page and I want to change the tab order within that form, but not disrupt the rest of tab flow of the document. I basically have two buttons which I'd like swap their tab order. I've tried tabindex 0, -1, along with a few others. Setting them, messes up the natural order as it tabs to them before the links in the menu etc... I've seen some examples where tabindex is added to every tabbable element and then their values are set through javascript. I was hoping to avoid something like that. Also moving the buttons is not an option. The html is build to be responsive and they want the buttons to line up a certain way on mobile devices. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: It might be kind of a hack, but I wonder if you could use CSS to have them in the desired order in the DOM while still having them display in the order you want (e.g., absolutely position them where you want).

Comment: Relevant docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.tabIndex

Answer (score 4):

There is just one tabbing order for a document, so if you set `tabindex` for just two elements, you inevitably affect the order as a whole: then these elements will be in the order before any elements that lack that attribute. So to make them appear in their natural place, you need to set `tabindex` on all elements before them.

As a workaround, you might consider embedding the form via `iframe`. A document so embedded has its own tabbing order.

Alternatively, as @DerekKurth suggests in a comment, make the source order of the elements the desired tabbing order and format the visual order with CSS.

Best of all, don’t create the problem. It is always a deviation from good usability and accessibility if the tabbing order differs from the apparent order.